# unable to create drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Actually I am trying to create drupal module  .  But I am Faild

Here is my Code  . I just want to display Iframe by using module .

**CODE (MY_info.info):**

```
name = MY_info
description = embedded widget
core = 7.x
```

**CODE (My_info.module)**

```
/**
 * @file
 * MY_info.module
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MY_info_menu() {
  $items = array();
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MY_info_form_alter() {

}
```

Can Anyone hel me how to create it . ?

Comment: just want to confirm, whether your custom module listed in Module listing page or not? if yes, will you be able to enable it?

Comment: yup... its display on module page.. after enable nothing happend

Comment: Just want to debug whether this module works or not. please replace your code function MY_info_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){ drupal_set_message($form_id); } and clear cache for once. if form id start displaying on top of the screen either node/add or admin screen, that means your module is enabled and works fine. you just need to work on your code to display the iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Need To Create Block Module To Display Iframe
use [hook_block_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) ; [hook_block_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7);

**Try This One CODE (My_info.module)**

```
<?php

function MY_info_block_info() {

  $blocks['MY_info_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Your Content For Block Menu'),
    // DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE will be assumed.
  );

  return $blocks;
}


function MY_info_block_view($delta = '') {
  // This example is adapted from node.module.
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {

    case 'MY_info_block':

        $block['subject'] = t('Your Block Title');

          $block['content'] = "Your Html Content";

      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```